# Track events " Removing the application of IOS or Android"

Tags: android, ios, iphone, analytics, google-play

Good day!
How can I track / analyze how many users have deleted my application ? IOS and Android.
Thank you!

Comment: For iOS you can't. There is no way to tell wether an app is removed or not. Installed is also hard since if the user installs your app but never starts it there is no way to tell.

Answer (score 0):

For Android you can get it from DEVELOPER CONSOLE.

In All Application tab you can see Current/Total installs.

Current count will be the active devices of your app .

Answer (score 0):

The only chance to get a rough figure is to implement a central service that is pinged regularly by your apps with a unique ID so that you know how many devices are alive. It is of course only a rough number as it does not take into account when the device is offline.
As Suhail already pointed out you can get total numbers for Android from the console.